# Vectorise Function call with Matrix argument

Tags: matlab

Can I vectorise this for loop?

```
F=zeros(de.nP,1);

for i=1:de.nP 
   F(i)=OF(P1(:,i)',data);
end

function ObjVal=OF(beta, data)
  mats=data.mats;
  yM=data.yM;
  model=data.model;
  y=model(beta,mats);
  aux=y-yM;
  ObjVal=dot(aux,aux);
end
```

When I simply try to do it like this:

```
 F=OF(P1,data);
```

It passes all of P1 at the same time but I want it to just pass one column of P1 at a time?

Comment: i just came here to say i admire your username

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the `model` command; is this from a Matlab toolbox?

Comment: We need to know what the model function does. Can you provide it's definition?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like `model` expects beta to be a 1xN array, and returns a 1xM array. So you first need to modify `model` to take an de.nP x N array for beta, and to return a de.nP x M array (and you will want to vectorize the calculations in model).

I'm not sure what to do about yM. If it is just a number, you don't need to change anything. If it is a 1xM array itself, then you need to do

```
aux=y-repmat(yM, [size(y,1) 1]);
```

Then you want to replace

```
ObjVal=dot(aux,aux);
```

with

```
ObjVal=dot(aux,aux,2);
```

I'll add the caveat that unless you provide us with code that can actually run (i.e. that doesn't depend on external stuff like the definition of `de` and `model`), it's hard to give a definitive answer.

**Edit** Oh, I guess you'll need to replace your for loop with something like

```
F=OF(P1',data);
```

**Edit**

I think the following correctly vectorizes your `model` function:

```
function y = NSS(beta, mats)
    gam1 = (1./beta(:,5)) * mats;
    gam2 = (1./beta(:,6)) * mats;
    aux1=1-exp(-gam1);
    aux2=1-exp(-gam2);
    y = repmat(beta(:,1), [1 length(mats)]) + ...
        repmat(beta(:,2), [1 length(mats)]) .* (aux1./gam1) + ...
        repmat(beta(:,3), [1 length(mats)]) .* (aux1./gam1 + aux1 - 1) + ...
        repmat(beta(:,4), [1 length(mats)]) .* (aux2./gam2 + aux2 - 1);
end
```

Again, since I can't run your code, I'm not 100% sure this will work, but I think it's OK.

Comment: function y=NSS(beta, mats)

gam1=mats./beta(5);
gam2=mats./beta(6);
aux1=1-exp(-gam1);
aux2=1-exp(-gam2);
y=beta(1)+beta(2)*(aux1./gam1)+beta(3)*(aux1./gam1+aux1-1)+beta(4)*(aux2./gam2+aux2-1);

end

Comment: The above is "model" in the original post, model is infact the function handle "@NSS". The handle is stored in the struct object data. data.yM is an 1*15 array and beta is a 1*6 array

Comment: model(@NSS) returns a 1*15 array

Comment: Lastly yM is also a 1*15 array and its what y is compared to

Comment: Is this enough of do you need more info?